# importing js file into ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

I've already read several posts concerning this. My approach was working yesterday but today it is failing. I'm importing a js file into a ts file. `allowJs` is set to `true` in `tsconfig.json`.

Getting the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/core/input-parser.service.ts(5,26): error TS2497: Module '".../dashboard/shared/models/ecn-info"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
```

**input-parser.service.ts:**

```
import * as EcnInfo from '../../../../shared/models/ecn-info';
```

**ecn-info.js:**

```
class EcnInfo {
  constructor(name, structure, status) {
    this.name = name;
    this.structure = structure;
    this.status = status;
  }
}

module.exports = EcnInfo;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use an `export default` in your `ecn-info.js` file:

```
export default class EcnInfo {
    constructor(name, structure, status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.structure = structure;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

2. Disable `noImplicitAny` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false
    ...
  }
}
```

3. Import like this:

```
import EcnInfo from '../../../../shared/models/ecn-info';
```

### Update

Here is an approach without using default export:

1. Use an `export` in your `ecn-info.js` file:

```
export class EcnInfo {
    constructor(name, structure, status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.structure = structure;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

2. Disable `noImplicitAny` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false
    ...
  }
}
```

3. Import like this:

```
import {EcnInfo} from '../../../../shared/models/ecn-info';
```

Comment: thanks for answering.. after trying your suggestion:

`ERROR in app/core/input-parser.service.ts(5,8): error TS1192: Module '".../dashboard/shared/models/ecn-info"' has no default export.`

Comment: I made a mistake in my snippet for `ecn-info.js`. I updated it - added the `default` keyword. Let me know how it works now.

Comment: And also added another option - without using default export.